# Flash Builder error 1120 Access of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

could someone explain to me, why the Flash Builder tells me error 1120  Access of undefined property value? Thank you for every advice :-)

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        var value:Number = 5;
        if(value == 5) {

            trace("value is 5");    
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put random ActionScript code in your MXML file.  The if statement needs to be moved into a method; kinda like this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    var value:Number = 5;

    protected function myMethod():void{
            if(value == 5) {

                trace("value is 5");    
            } 
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

I also recommend scoping the value declaration, like this:

```
   public var value:Number = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are tracing the value without any method call. You put your "if condition" in a method and call this method. I think it should definitely work.

```
protected function yourMethod():void{
var value:int = 5;
        if(value == 5) {
            trace("value is 5");    
        } 
}
]]>
```